# Как удалить все нечисловые значения из датафрейма?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Есть следующий код:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

currencyf = pd.read_csv('/content/drive/MyDrive/Без названия/worldwide internet prices in 2022 - IN 2022.csv')
chst = currencyf['Cheapest 1GB for 30 days (USD)']
exst = currencyf['Most expensive 1GB (USD)']

# for i in chst:
#   if i != np.nan:
#     print(i)
#   else:
#     continue

print(chst)
```

Мне необходимо извлечь из chst и exst все нечисловые значения NaN. Я попытался сделать это через .dropna — не вышло, через for (что закомментировано) — тоже, через фильтрацию исходного датафрейма — тоже самое. Так как же мне убрать все подобные значения, чтобы всё остальное преобразовать в числовые значения?

Файл: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mOXU48GaM7Bbv3zBxKaH4kTcVJoriC-1/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно использовать `.dropna()` с аргументом `subset` с последующим удалением `$` и преобразованием во `float` через `.astype()`

```
df = pd.read_csv(r'c:\test\worldwide internet prices in 2022 - IN 2022.csv')
df = df.dropna(subset=['Cheapest 1GB for 30 days (USD)', 'Most expensive 1GB (USD)'])
df['Cheapest 1GB for 30 days (USD)'] = df['Cheapest 1GB for 30 days (USD)'].str.lstrip('$').astype(float)
df['Most expensive 1GB (USD)'] = df['Most expensive 1GB (USD)'].str.lstrip('$').astype(float)
print(df)
```

```
    Country code                   Name  Continental region  NO. OF Internet Plans  Average price of 1GB (USD)  Cheapest 1GB for 30 days (USD)  Most expensive 1GB (USD) Average price of 1GB (USD  at the start of 2021) Average price of 1GB (USD – at start of 2020)
0             IL                 Israel           NEAR EAST                    27.0                      $0.05                            0.02                     20.95                                            $0.11                                         $0.90
1             KG             Kyrgyzstan   CIS (FORMER USSR)                    20.0                      $0.15                            0.10                      7.08                                            $0.21                                         $0.27
2             FJ                   Fiji             OCEANIA                    18.0                      $0.19                            0.05                      0.85                                            $0.59                                         $3.57
3             IT                  Italy      WESTERN EUROPE                    29.0                      $0.27                            0.09                      3.54                                            $0.43                                         $1.73
4             SD                  Sudan  SUB-SAHARAN AFRICA                    33.0                      $0.27                            0.03                      0.92                                            $0.63                                         $0.68
..           ...                    ...                 ...                     ...                        ...                             ...                       ...                                              ...                                           ...
225           MW                 Malawi  SUB-SAHARAN AFRICA                     5.0                     $25.46                           20.37                     25.46                                           $27.41                                         $3.59
226           ST  São Tomé and Príncipe  SUB-SAHARAN AFRICA                    16.0                     $30.97                           13.27                    121.65                                           $28.26                                         $5.33
227           SH           Saint Helena  SUB-SAHARAN AFRICA                     4.0                     $39.87                           38.57                     51.42                                           $52.50                                         $6.04
228           FK       Falkland Islands       SOUTH AMERICA                     4.0                     $44.56                           29.71                     82.26                                           $40.41                                        $55.47
229           GQ      Equatorial Guinea  SUB-SAHARAN AFRICA                     4.0                     $49.67                           45.16                     63.22                                           $12.78                                        $47.39

[230 rows x 9 columns]
```

Если нужно все колонки с ценами сделать числовыми, то можно так:

```
df = pd.read_csv(r'c:\test\worldwide internet prices in 2022 - IN 2022.csv')
df = df.dropna(subset=['Cheapest 1GB for 30 days (USD)', 'Most expensive 1GB (USD)'])
df = df.replace({'NO PACKAGES': np.nan})
df.loc[:, 'Average price of 1GB (USD)':] = df.loc[:, 'Average price of 1GB (USD)':].apply(
    lambda x: x.str.lstrip('$').astype(float))
print(df)
```